# Typescript -> Calling function which will call callback in another function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm asking maybe something too weird but i'm not sure

I'm trying to make .done() function in Typescript using OOP

My code looks like:

```
    // Calling this callback out of Class map/terrain
    terrain.done(() =>
    {
        // Do something when terrain is Done
    });
```

Another code is loading terrain, now i have function whit i want to run this callback.

```
   private loadTiledmap():void
   {
     .... //loadTiledmap is called when all resources are loaded
       this.done; // Trigger the callback
   }

   public done(callback: () => void ): void
   {
       callback();
   }
```

The both this.done and terrain.done(() will call the callback, but i have no idea how to trigger terrain.done(() somewhere else in code. Thanks for all your helps and tips

Comment: I may be missing what you're looking to accomplish with this function.  But generally if you're performing an asynchronous operation and want the user to be able to attach a `.done()` callback (or `.then()` I suppose) then you'd return a `Promise` from that operation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: as it's written, any time `done()` is called, it will just instantly call the function that was passed to it without waiting! if you would like to attach a callback that can be called later, consider using an EventEmitter, otherwise *store* the callback when `done()` is called (don't call it instantly) and execute that callback if it exists in `loadTiledmap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `done(callback)` to register the callback, and then you want to `loadTiledmap` to call that callback when it's completed it's work?

In that case, you just need to save the function on your class instance, and then run that callback.

```
class MyClass {
    private doneCallback: (() => void) | undefined

    // Save the callback function
    public done(callback: () => void ): void
    {
        this.doneCallback = callback;
    }

    private loadTiledmap():void
    {
       // ... loadTiledmap is called when all resources are loaded
       this.doneCallback?.(); // Trigger the callback
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoavoAcAnASwDcwAXAU2gBMB7AOysTBBACMxgBrALmgAKQQEpoAXgB80UvWK0xAH2gBXRrSoAzYs1rZseaAHoj0AMphSNCgAsawNp249omtcArEmBvPhUcQYmA6JipBB3YuXgFRCWlZeWgRAQS9HDxMdMNcW2IIADoGZlZI5wloCKdeAG4fXABffSyCf0DgkHowWjMKFU1NUTr0IcNcgo6ugBViECpaAFswfEHmxqwhojJKGgnaadmFpdE+VKHM7NwTaHyb6F39ucX8aDyKxznoAHc7RmhHaEIVAg9BUhGAQL+gLunQ0aQu0DGhVCJSqPAA-PlRNVjKZJiQAOb4qiEBF2N6lXhDNZrbDAJgQCgvRgMsCMcHlZifOBIFAQFY6FlsqhI5jCMRSCr0+izfIdfGCADk2kYeTstAVIhE2AFFFZ4NlMJ6fQGYiucpgACJlaq5haEfRSfYpbMgA)